# UdpSocket recv_from performance issues

Tags: udp, rust

I'm not sure if this is a language specific problem, but I might as well try.
For a project in our company we're trying to implement a data transfer protocol of 22MB large files through UDP. We know TCP is better suited for this, but the hardware development decided it's got to be UDP.
 
The logic we've got is the client sends the 22MB file through 1500 byte sized packages. Each package has a unique ID in its header. The first batch of these ~15000 packages takes about a second to transmit, but we of course lose ~2000 packages due to UDP being used.
 
Every batch of packages ends with a unique "end package", telling us, that the transfer from the client has finished, and we can start requesting lost packages through their unique ID. Because of limitations we are only allowed to request 255 packages at a time, so we've got to send a lot of resend-requests. Due to the end-package we don't have to use a socket timeout, which would have to be ~250ms per request cycle to be efficient in not leaving out still to be transmitted packages, resulting in a lot of lost time.
 
Now for the actual issue at hand:
While the first cycle of requesting 255 packages and receiving them takes 0.01s, each one after that takes 0.4s. I've tracked down the root of the problem to the "recv_from" function. I've made sure that it receives the same amount of packages in every cycle before ending at the "end-package", and although it's even down to the exact same amount of bytes, it takes a 40-fold the time.

```
fn receive( socket: &UdpSocket, buf: &mut [u8;1600] ) -> Vec<Vec<u8>>{
    let mut res: Vec<Vec<u8>> = vec![];

    let mut x = Duration::seconds( 0 );
    loop{
        // time tracking
        let start = PreciseTime::now();
        let ( n, _ ) = socket.recv_from( buf ).unwrap();
        let end = PreciseTime::now();
        x = x + ( start.to( end ));

        // difference in time doesn't occur here
        let mut v = vec![];
        v.push_all( &buf[ 0..n ]);

        // this is an end-package
        if v[8] == 240 {
            break;
        }
        res.push( v );

    }
    // first call of this function with 255 received package takes 0.01s, each consecutive call takes 0.4s
    println!{ "NOTE: Total transmission time: {}s", x };

    // the higher this value, the less the difference in times between the first and the consecutive calls
    // at ~ 500ms it evens out at about 0.02s per call of 255 received packages
    sleep_ms( 100 );
 res
}
```

Sorry for the huge wall of text, it's just a lot of background that comes with this problem; not even sure if I mentioned everything that's relevant.

Comment: This was [cross-posted to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3ipqto/udpsocket_recv_from_performance/)

Comment: The Reddit threat says it was a kernel issue of Windows and solved by moving to Linux.